# Encoding Problems with C++ std::string to C# managed System::String

Tags: c#, string, visual-c++, data-conversion, managed

I'm implementing a C++ DLL which has to interoperate with C# code (and Unity framework), hence I need to be able to convert a `std::string` to `System::String` in C++. For this purpose, I wrote the following code:

```
app::String* native_string_to_managed_string(const std::string& native_string)
{
    const auto encoding = (*app::Encoding__TypeInfo)->static_fields->utf8Encoding;
    const auto managed_string = app::String_CreateStringFromEncoding((uint8_t*)&native_string.at(0),
                                                                     static_cast<int32_t>(native_string.size()), encoding, nullptr);

    return managed_string;
}
```

The called function is defined as:
`String * String_CreateStringFromEncoding(uint8_t *bytes, int32_t byteLength, Encoding *encoding, MethodInfo *method)`

`(*app::Encoding__TypeInfo)->static_fields->utf16Encoding` does not exist, either.

This seems to work fine for ASCII strings but as soon as I use e.g. Chinese symbols in the `std::string`, the conversion seems to be wrong since passing the managed string into a C# method afterwards causes a crash. I suppose the memory layout of strings is different among both languages so doing the conversion this way is problematic.

Is there any fool-proof way to convert a `std::string` to a `System::String` and vice versa with full UTF-8 support? My debugger showed the Chinese symbols correctly in the `std::string` variable, from the C++ layer there didn't seem to be an issue and obviously `System::String` supports UTF-8 as well.

Comment: [marshal_as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-as)

Comment: The VS debugger doesn't know utf-8, it displays 8-bit strings by assuming Encoding.Default.  In other words, if it looks good then *native_string* is not encoded with utf-8.  So it is probably a garbage-in-garbage out problem.  Fix the string or use the proper *encoding*.

Comment: Hmm, `marshal_as` only works when I modify plenty of compile flags and link to e.g. 
`mscorlib.dll` (which is a C# DLL). Overall, that doesn't seem worth it. Converting the std::string to UTF-8 also yielded the same std::string again, code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21575607/3764804

Comment: The link to `marshal_as` was a *not-so-subtle suggestion* to build a C++/CLI dll, given that interop with C# is what you're after (C# strings are UTF16LE encoded, though the marshaller on the C# side can be instructed to transcode *ANSI* [local encoding] strings / `wchar_t*`  /  `TEXT()` (`LPTSTR` / `LPWSTR`) to Unicode)